# Unable to capture available state..?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on anylogic as beginner, and I have issue with adding statistic into analysis.

I am unable to find any obvious question.

Please, let me clarify on this.

[The matter illustrate in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Cne.png)

Thank you

Asanka

Comment: your code line (item.inState...) is correct but in the wrong place. What object is the statistic "IsAttending" in? It should be on a population of "Function" agents on Main (in which case it should work).

Answer (score 1):

`Function` is name of another class, used in AnyLogic. Using this name, you refer to the class, not to the agent type. Use full name of the agent type — `modelPackageName.Function.Working`. Also, you may simply rename `Function` agent type to `FunctionAgent` or other one.